# ASP.NET Core targeting .NET Framework 4.6.1 missing some assemblies available in ASP.NET Core targeting .NET Core 2.1?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

I begin my first ASP.NET Core project targeting .net core 2.1 and while i advance in the project i see that i need some nuget package that ar not available on .NET Core so after i decide to create a new ASP.NET Core application that target .NET Framework 4.6.1 but i discover that somme assemblies present in ASP.NET Core (Targeting .NET Core 2.1) are missing. Why and what can i do to import them

Sone Missing Assemblies in ASP.NET Core targeting .NET Framework 4.6.1
[image: some missing assemblies]

ASP.NET Core targeting .NET Framework 4.6.1
[image: AspCore Targeting .net framework]

ASP.NET Core targeting .NET Core 2.1
[image: AspCore Targeting .net core]

Comment: you cannot create a .net framework 4.6.1 application and make it work with .net core assemblies. If you are missing libraries from .net framework, you better create a .net framework application. (.net core works on unix, .net framework doesn't - you're trying to make .net framework functions run on unix - that won't work.)

Comment: What are the missing assemblies ? May be you can have them in netstandard.

Comment: You can install all missing libs from NuGet if they're targeting netstandard 2.0. One advice, if you create a new project, target .NET 4.7.2

Comment: thanks @Roxtar for now i follow your advice and it work fine  i continue to integrate assemblies that are not available in .net core. what i undertand is that when you create a new asp.net core project targeting .net core VS install the package Microsoft.AspNetCore.App which depend on Microsoft.AspNetCore package and other packages  its a bundle . but when you create asp.net core project targeting .net framework this bundle package doesnt exit and VS install Microsoft.AspNetCore so you have to install the over package manualy.

Comment: Have no idea why not try to upgrade the entire project to .NET Core. Since all you referenced are all supported in .NET Core.

Comment: Hello @Anduin this question was asked since 2 years. for now the project run on .Net 5 thanks